# How to access dynamic key from dictionary

Tags: python

```
token='10877186'
data = {'10877186': {'instrument_token': 10877186, 'last_price': 418}}
```

how to get `last_price` from the above dictionary in python? token is dynamic..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data can be indexed:

```
my_last_price = data[token]["last_price"]
```

otherwise import the json library to convert the json value from a string into a python dictionary and do the same call as above.